# Is there a way to get validity (notAfter) from a openssl certificate fingerprint and no certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, fingerprint, sha, jruby-openssl

Is there a way I can determine when a particular certificate fingerprint without having the certificate itself?

something like
`OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"+cert+"\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n")` but from a certificate fingerprint?

background: i've authentication being done using this certificate and end users are allowed to input either certificate or its fingerprint to enable authentication from my side

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this will be possible to do the reverse, due to the fact that the fingerprint is generated as a hash, which is a one-way operation.